# VB.NET get data from ODBC as JSON

Tags: json, vb.net, odbc, datareader

I'm not very familiar with .NET so I'm not even sure I know how to ask this question in the proper terms, because I have to believe this is a common use case, but my google-fu is pathetic.

In PHP if I want to get data from a database, and format it as JSON I would use PDO something like this:

```
$query = $this->dbConn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Customers");
$query->execute();
$resultsSet = $query->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ( $resultsSet as $row  ){
    $json = json_encode( $row );
    //POST $json to web service or something
}
```

This will create JSON in the format of {"Column Name": "Column Value", "Column Name": "Column Value", ...} which is exactly what I want.

How would I do this in VB.NET? I can retrieve data from my datasource using OdbcDataReader like this:

```
Dim Conn As New OdbcConnection("[connection string]")
Dim Cmd As New OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers", Conn)
Dim Reader As OdbcDataReader
Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()

Conn.Open()
Reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader()

While (Reader.Read())
    json = serializer.Serialize(Reader).ToString 
    'this doesn't work - returns [{"FieldCount":126},{"FieldCount":126},{"FieldCount":126}...]  
    'POST json to web service
End While
```

Essentially what I need to do is periodically read straight through about 100 rather large files (million plus records) from a legacy application using that app's ODBC driver, converting it to JSON and posting it to a remote web service.

It's important that the JSON contains the name/value pairs in the form of "column name": "column value".  I'm open to alternative suggestions.

I'm using VS 2017, .NET 4.6

Comment: Define `this doesn't work`

Comment: I get [{"FieldCount":126},{"FieldCount":126},{"FieldCount":126}...]

Comment: So you are going to send 1,000,000+ data rows somewhere one at a time...on purpose?  A DataReader isnt going to have the data in any meaningful structure that the serializer can do anything with (and ToString would sidestep it anyway).  It is tedious to fetch data from a reader for much the same reason.

Comment: Yes. I needed to send data from a proprietary black box to a REST endpoint that was written to accept 1 record of data.  I had them modify the endpoint to accept an array of records in a single chunk of JSON, and they can easily convert that to an array and loop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Newtonsoft.Json nuget package to the project
Instead of a reader use a DataAdapter and a DataTable

```
DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)
```

Then pass the DataTable to this little function

```
Public Function DataTableToJSONWithJSONNet(table As DataTable) As String
        Dim JSONString As String = String.Empty
        JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table)
        Return JSONString
End Function
```

Comment: That will put all the records in one JSON string.  It may well work, but the post  indicates there are 126ish columns, so 126*1,000,000 could exceed something somewhere.  Or maybe the receiver/API expects just one at a time.  In either case you'd have to do something differently.  The OP wouldnt explain to allow alternatives to be offered

Comment: I ended up with using this.  The REST endpoint was written to accept one record at a time, which is why I wanted to use the data reader, but I had them modify it to accept multiple records in a single chunk of JSON.   What I ended up doing to preserve memory is get the data from the ODBC driver in chunks using the driver's OFFSET and LIMIT, and grab 1000 rows at a time and ship them over the wire.  THanks for the help - I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around .NET.